# remove spaces/commas from a variable to add to a string

Tags: python

I need it to look like

```
https://doorpasscode.kringlecastle.com/checkpass.php?i= (3333)&resourceId=77af125f-213f-4b2b-9e1e-ce156b6a838c
```

instead it looks like

```
https://doorpasscode.kringlecastle.com/checkpass.php?i= (3, 3, 3, 3)&resourceId=77af125f-213f-4b2b-9e1e-ce156b6a838c
```

Code:

```
for i in range(0, 4):
    for j in range(0, 4):
        for k in range(0, 4):
            for l in range(0, 4):
                trypass=(i,j,k,l)
                #print(i,j,k,l, sep='')
                print('https://doorpasscode.kringlecastle.com/checkpass.php?i= {}&resourceId=77af125f-213f-4b2b-9e1e-ce156b6a838c'.format(trypass).strip(','))
```

Comment: I'm not understanding the groups of 4. Why are you using ranges of 4?

Comment: @Polkaguy6000 Presumably to include values like `0000` (rather than just 0) in the set of attempts. (There are other ways, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

1. `strip` only strips from the beginning and end of the string, it doesn't strip the characters from the middle.
2. Your problem isn't really stripping, it's adding unnecessary junk in the first place by directly stringifying the `tuple`.

To fix both, convert `trypass` to a string up front with no joiner characters in the middle:

```
trypass = ''.join(map(str, (i,j,k,l)))
```

A side-note: You could shorten this a lot with `itertools.product` to turn four loops into one (no arrow shaped code), and avoid repeatedly stringifying by converting the `range` elements to `str` only once, directly generating `trypass` without the intermediate named variables:

```
from itertools import product

for trypass in map(''.join, product(map(str, range(0, 4)), repeat=4)):
    print('https://doorpasscode.kringlecastle.com/checkpass.php?i= ({})&resourceId=77af125f-213f-4b2b-9e1e-ce156b6a838c'.format(trypass).)
```

Answer (score 0):

`.format(trypass)` will format the tuple as a string using the default tuple formatting rules, e.g. `(3, 3, 3, 3)`.  Instead you should explicitly tell it how to format the string, like:

```
.format(''.join(str(i) for i in trypass))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a tuple that you want to reduce to a string.

```
>>> trypass = (3,3,3,3)
>>> ''.join(str(i) for i in trypass)
'3333'
```

Or, since you know there are exactly 4 digits,

```
print('https://doorpasscode.kringlecastle.com/checkpass.php?i={}{}{}{}&resourceId=77af125f-213f-4b2b-9e1e-ce156b6a838c'.format(*trypass))
```

Or, just iterate over the 4-digit numbers directly. `itertools.product` can generate the tuples for you.

```
import itertools
for trypass in itertools.product("0123", repeat=4):
    print('https://doorpasscode.kringlecastle.com/checkpass.php?i={}{}{}{}&resourceId=77af125f-213f-4b2b-9e1e-ce156b6a838c'.format(*trypass))
```

Comment: That final option will iterate numbers with digits from 4-9 in them, which the original code won't (it only uses 0-3).

Comment: Oops, didn't look closely enough at the ranges. Will fix.